# Text beside and under a photo

Tags: xsl-fo, textflow

i am trying to put some text beside a photo and i want this text to flow under the image as following. **I use FOP 1.0 so i can't really use the float element**

[image]

I tried to do it with absolute positioning of a block-container but then the text goes under the image, too.

```
<fo:block >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//StringValue[@name='myString']/Value/node()" />
<fo:block-container   width="140px" wrap-option="wrap" >
    <fo:block >
        <fo:external-graphic content-height="3.4cm"     
        content-width="5.3cm" scaling="scale-to-fit" src="{//StringValue[@name = 'photo']/Value}" />
    </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>   
</fo:block>
```

any clues?

Comment: That is exactly what a float is. You need latest FOP for limited support fo floats.

Comment: I know it is supported only partialy by FOP2.0 . I thought there was some nasty workaround that i m not aware of but yeah... anyway

Comment: The only workaround I see for this would be to use a table.